# Azure Logic App - FTP connection download zip file to blob storage - output zip file corrupted

Tags: ftp, azure-logic-apps, zip

I've set up the pipeline and it works (I followed this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-ftp), it downloads the zip file and loads it to the blob storage.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sm3Ex.png]

[image: create blob]

however the resulted zip file is corrupted. it has a slightly different size than the original file.

[image: zip file corrupted]

I set the infer content type to YES. Also tried this setting to no but didn't change result.

[image: infer content type]

I tried with hardcoded and dynamic naming.

[image: dynamic name]